# Freeswitch : start_dtmf not detecting DTMF

Tags: freeswitch

I have read about start_dtmf application in freeswitch which is used to detect in-band dtmf.
I have tested this ,but it didn't detect any DTMF.

```
<extension name="dtmf_test">
<condition field="destination_number" expression="^6000$">
<action application="answer"/>
<action application="start_dtmf"/>
<action application="bridge" data="user/6888"/>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but worth another shot at the answer.

**Assumption**

I'm making one assumption that the user/6888 is the originator of the dtmf digits.

**Problem**

An important thing to remember with any calling based application is that it deals in call legs/channels, callee, caller or a-leg, b-leg. This is very important when executing dialplan based applications that are leg specific (ie. only enabled on one leg), like 'start_dtmf', see the [documentation](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_start_dtmf) particularly the line that states :

> The start_dtmf line listed above starts the start_dtmf application on **this** channel to allow for DTMF detection.

In your example, the start_dtmf application is listening on the user who called 6000, not the bridged extension user/6888. The freeswitch example works because it's dialing into an IVR, and the incoming caller is pressing the dtmf digits.

**Solution**

To set the start_dtmf application on the other leg, you want to look at the [exec_after_bridge application](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Variable_exec_after_bridge_app).

```
<action application="set" data="exec_after_bridge_app=start_dtmf"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I find [`mod_spandsp`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_spandsp)'s in-band DTMF detection more reliable than the in-built FreeSwitch detection. Also I found it did not work on Windows, only on Linux.

Comment: how do you use the mod_spandsp for detecting tones?

Answer (score 0):

how do you know that it's not working?

1) Be sure that the phone path is using in-band DTMFs
What kind of SIP user agents or phones are involved in this test call? Softphones usually have the option to change DTMF settings.

2) Be sure to have your console log set to DEBUG to see if DTMFs get recognized.
Usually you can set it in DEBUG by pressing the F8 key at the FreeSWITCH console.

Ciao!

Comment: In Mac book what is the F8 key?

Comment: @YumYumYum type `console loglevel DEBUG` in FreeSwitch console to set log level to debug. F8 is just a Windows shortcut for this command

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**
the same as @bencode opinion, your xml starts dtmf in a-channel but not in b-channel

**Solution**
however in my config, just `set exec_after_bridge_app=start_dtmf` doesn't work
I tried another way to enable dtmf in b-channel

```xml
<action application="export" data="execute_on_answer=start_dtmf"/>
```

which will execute start_dtmf in a-channel and b-channel when call establish